# swift upload image to server use image as parameter

Tags: asp.net, swift, swift2, image-uploading, postman

I try to upload image to server and test it use postman. it works. In header I use Authorization bearer uniqueID. In body I set form-data with image as key. It got 200 as response as attachment below.
[image]

But when I try use swift like this, it got 500 as response:

```
let url = NSURL(string: Constant.TestUpload())
let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("bearer \(uniqueID)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
if (photouser.image == nil){
    return
}else{
    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photouser.image!)
    if(image_data == nil){
         return
    }else{
         let body = NSMutableData()
         let fname = "\(userID).png"
         let mimetype = "image/png"
         body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
         body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
         body.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
         body.appendData(image_data!)
                body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
         body.appendData("--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
         request.HTTPBody = body
         let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
         let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
             (data, response, error) -> Void in
             if let unwrappedData = data {
                  do {
                     print("response:\(response!)")
                     if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                          if response.statusCode == 200 {
                             let json:AnyObject! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(unwrappedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! AnyObject
                             print("json:\(json)")
                             let jsonuser = self.convertStringToDictionary("\(json)")
                             print("jsonuser:\(jsonuser)")
                             let imageFile:String = jsonuser!["imageFile"] as! String
                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                         self.photouser.layer.borderWidth = 1
                                        self.photouser.layer.masksToBounds = false
                                        self.photouser.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
                                        self.photouser.layer.cornerRadius = self.photouser.frame.height/2
                                        self.photouser.clipsToBounds = true
                                        self.photouser.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://10.8.8.249/profile/\(imageFile)")!)!)
                                        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                                        alertView.title = "Profile photo updated!"
                                        alertView.message = "Success update profile photo"
                                        alertView.delegate = self
                                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                                        alertView.show()
                                    }
                                }else if response.statusCode == 500 {
                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                                        alertView.title = "Failed to upload image!"
                                        alertView.message = "Server error"
                                        alertView.delegate = self
                                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                                        alertView.show()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Failed to update profile photo: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        }
```

this is response log:

```
{ URL: http://10.8.8.249/users/uploadtest } { status code: 500, headers {
"Content-Length" = 36;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 07 Dec 2016 05:58:45 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
```

I check response 500 happens when key in body did not set or empty key like screenshot below:
[image]

How to correct my swift code, so I can upload image to server correctly (get response 200)?

update: try with this also did not work (500 as response):

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let fname = "\(userID).png"
                let mimetype = "image/png"
                let url = NSURL(string: Constant.TestUpload())
                let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
                request.setValue("bearer \(uniqueID)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                var base64String = image_data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                let params:[String: AnyObject] = ["image":[ "content_type": "\(mimetype)", "filename":"\(fname)", "file_data": base64String]]
                do{
                    request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
                    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                        if let unwrappedData = data {
                            do{
                                print("response:\(response!)")
                                if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                                    if response.statusCode == 200 {
                                        let json:AnyObject! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(unwrappedData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! AnyObject
                                        print("json:\(json)")
                                        let jsonuser = self.convertStringToDictionary("\(json)")
                                        print("jsonuser:\(jsonuser)")
                                        let imageFile:String = jsonuser!["imageFile"] as! String
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                            self.photouser.layer.borderWidth = 1
                                            self.photouser.layer.masksToBounds = false
                                            self.photouser.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
                                            self.photouser.layer.cornerRadius = self.photouser.frame.height/2
                                            self.photouser.clipsToBounds = true
                                            self.photouser.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://10.8.8.249/profile/\(imageFile)")!)!)
                                            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                                            alertView.title = "Profile photo updated!"
                                            alertView.message = "Success update profile photo"
                                            alertView.delegate = self
                                            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                                            alertView.show()
                                        }
                                    }else if response.statusCode == 500 {
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                                            alertView.title = "Failed to upload image!"
                                            alertView.message = "Server error"
                                            alertView.delegate = self
                                            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                                            alertView.show()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }catch{
                                print("Failed to update profile photo: \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    task.resume()
                }catch{
                    print ("Oops something wrong")
                }
```

Comment: Why don't you try Alamofire.

Comment: because I prefer use standart swift version.

Answer (score 0):

Try print() with your base64String and your "(userID)" & "(uniqueID)". Everything else looks right, I have a feeling these values aren't coming out as expected. Make sure to print them in quotes like did in var fname so you can see what the server is actually receiving.

Comment: I can get that userID and uniqueID with print. Nothing wrong with userID and uniqueID.

Answer (score 0):

As long you use Postman click on "Generate Code" button and choose Swift language and use this code to upload your image , hope to help .